# How to access the internal memory of HTC Explorer

Tags: internal-storage, boot, htc-explorer

I have HTC Explorer and with **Root Explorer** put a file into `/system/lib` directory.

After reset, the phone will not boot. Now I cannot access to the internal memory via the phone and I need to access it via the PC in order to delete the file from `/system/lib`.
How can I do it?

Comment: What file did you drop in there in the `/system/lib` directory that caused it to not to boot?

Comment: I do this http://www.neopeek.com/viewtopic.php?t=7937#p26166

Comment: Do not **ever** overwrite `libskia.so`! That was the reason that it refused to boot! `libskia.so` is responsible for rendering graphics and font faces and is tied in directly with the ROM when it was built! Dropping in that on another ROM is simply not going to work! Think of it this way, compiling a library that has dependencies on *Ubuntu* in-built libraries, and drop that library on *Debian* is **not going to work**...

Comment: Before the overwriting i renamed the original **libskia.so** to **libslia.so-back** against potential problems. Now is there a way to restore it?

Comment: Remove `/system/lib/libskia.so`, rename the original `libslia.so-back` to its original filename and you should be good...hopefully.... am assuming handset is rooted and that you have cwm recovery?

Comment: handset is rooted, but what is **cwm** recovery?

Comment: at now i find http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager

Comment: ROM Manager is not a good idea....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had ADB debugging enabled, there is an easy way to do this using the SDK.

All you have to do is connect the device to the computer while it is booting, and type:

```
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
rm -rvf /system/libskia.so
mv /system/libskia.so-back /system/libskia.so
```

To get the ADB binary you will have to download the Android SDK, or Google 'Android Mini SDK'.

If you didn't have USB debugging enabled, then the only thing you can do is flash a new ROM. You would have to install CWM recovery, and find a ROM for your device.

If your device has fastboot you can easily flash a recovery file *that has been made for your device* by using the `fastboot flash recovery <recovery .img file path>`.